# How to allow netNamedPipeBinding to work with requiring UAC?

Tags: c#, wcf, uac, netnamedpipebinding

I have a service running under Local system account. I have an application that run in a non-UAC mode. Both interact with each other as both act as server and client.

Application as client can communicate with Service. But Service as client cannot communicate with application.

If I run with UAC the problem is solved.

```
<customBinding>
   <binding name="net.pipe">
      <namedPipeTransport  />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is by design. ugh.

An excellent article clears named pipe binding  [Exploring the WCF Named Pipe Binding](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/05/19/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-1.aspx)